# BarCode Image Generator in Java

Tags: java, generator, barcode

How can I create a barcode image in Java?  I need something that will allow me to enter a number and produce the corresponding barcode image.  Is there a free library available for this type of task?

Comment: you can use barcode4j. A good example [here](http://naeemgik.blogspot.com/2013/10/generating-barcode-in-java-using.html)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

[iText](http://www.lowagie.com/iText/) is a great Java PDF library. They also have an API for creating barcodes. You don't need to be creating a PDF to use it.

This page has the details on [creating barcodes](http://itextdocs.lowagie.com/tutorial/objects/images/tiff/index.php). Here is an example from that site:

```
BarcodeEAN codeEAN = new BarcodeEAN();
codeEAN.setCodeType(codeEAN.EAN13);
codeEAN.setCode("9780201615883");
Image imageEAN = codeEAN.createImageWithBarcode(cb, null, null);
```

The biggest thing you will need to determine is what type of barcode you need. There are many different barcode formats and iText does support a lot of them. You will need to know what format you need before you can determine if this API will work for you.

Comment: @Chris Dail. Iwould like to clear my doubt. Is iText is free? can we use it for commercial projects

Comment: @Manish iText used to be free. It looks like it now requires a commercial license for commercial products.

Comment: @ChrisDail I am developing a software product for sale. Can I use iText for free

Comment: The problem is the iText barcode AWT image creator doesn't support options like text, or changing the width. You can do this for the PDF output but not AWT.

Comment: I'm wondering how you can suggest using iText without mentioning the implications the AGPL has..

Comment: According to their page iText com.lowagie classes has been deprecated in 2012. And seems it no longer an open API.

Answer (score 20):

There is also this free API that you can use to make free barcodes in java.

[Barbecue](http://barbecue.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Barbecue is only dependent on JDOM..  looked at it and Barcode4J, but didn't really like adding an Avalon dependency :-/

Answer (score 17):

There is a free library called [barcode4j](http://barcode4j.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Barcode4J is dependent on Avalon.. requires it for configuration at startup. Barbecue is only dependent on JDOM.

Comment: Avalon Framework is only needed if you want to configure Barcode4J using XML. If you work with [plain Java](http://barcode4j.sourceforge.net/latest/embedding-bean.html), it doesn't require JDOM nor Avalon.

Comment: It seems like Barcode4j only supports a subset of all available barcode formats when using beans.
Also Avalon framework had been retired for a whie.
Barbecue is still in beta with no updates since 2007. Things don't look promising.

Answer (score 12):

[ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) is a free open source Java library to read and generate barcode images. You need to get the source code and build the jars yourself. Here's a [simple tutorial](http://www.vineetmanohar.com/2010/09/java-barcode-api/) that I wrote for building with ZXing jars and writing your first program with ZXing.

[http://www.vineetmanohar.com/2010/09/java-barcode-api/]

Comment: Is available on maven central. of the recommendations given, this appears to be (by a huge margin), the best choice.

Answer (score 9):

I use 
[barbeque](http://sourceforge.net/projects/barbecue/)
, it's great, and supports a very wide range of different barcode formats.
See if you like 
[its API](http://barbecue.sourceforge.net/apidocs/overview-tree.html)
.

Sample API:

```
public static Barcode createCode128(java.lang.String data)
                             throws BarcodeException
```

> Creates a Code 128 barcode that
>   dynamically switches between character
>   sets  to give the smallest possible
>   encoding. This will encode  all
>   numeric characters, upper and lower
>   case alpha characters and control
>   characters  from the standard ASCII
>   character set. The size of the barcode
>   created will be the  smallest possible
>   for the given data, and use of this
>   "optimal" encoding will  generally
>   give smaller barcodes than any of the
>   other 3 "vanilla" encodings.