# Create barcode image in java?

Tags: java

I need to create barcode image in java;According to the user inputs (int) i have to create bar code image in java. How to do this in java?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700597/barcode-image-generator-in-java) is solution
also
Check [barbecue](http://barbecue.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

You may try [Aspose.Barcode for Java](http://www.aspose.com/categories/java-components/aspose.barcode-for-java/default.aspx) to [create barcode images in Java](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/java-components/aspose.barcode-for-java/using-with-java-desktop-applications.html) applications. The API is quite simple to learn and use.

Disclosure: I work as developer evangelist at Aspose.

Answer (score 0):

Try iText. Its the best. i have personally used it.