# How to display a 1-D barcode from string in Android?

Tags: android, barcode, barcode-scanner, zxing

I am using ZXing via intent to scan 1D bar-codes.  ZXing sends me back the type of 1D barcode that was scanned (UPC-A, Code 39, etc...) and the string that is encoded in the barcode.  I would like to take the type and string and generate and image of the 1D barcode and display it in an ImageView in an activity.

I am also open to displaying the barcode in a TextView using a font similar to "Free 3 of 9", but I cannot figure out how to do this.

I noticed that there is an activity in ZXing called EncodeActivity that can perform what I need, but only for QR codes.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Try this one: http://barcode4j.sourceforge.net/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I couldn't find an example on their site that did import something from awt though.

Comment: Anyway, some implementation details can be taken from that library (encoding details, etc...)

Comment: True, I've given you the point because that definitely is possible, but I was hoping to implement a solution that might take less effort. Thanks, but I'm still looking for an easier solution.

Comment: If online variant is suitable you can try this one: http://www.bcgen.com/linear-barcode-creator.html

Comment: Also, check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700597/barcode-image-generator-in-java

Comment: I couldn't get any of those to work.

Comment: Could you solved?. I have to do the same and I can't understand how to do??

Comment: Nope, sorry, I had to generate it on the server and save the barcode image on the phone.  I wasn't able to generate it on the phone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using ZXing `IntentIntegrator` and `IntentResult` classes!

```
    String data = "123456789";

    Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.ENCODE");  

    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT); 

    intent.putExtra("ENCODE_FORMAT", "CODE_128");  

    intent.putExtra("ENCODE_DATA", data);  

    startActivity(intent);
```

It only works if you have the [Barcode reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android) installed on your Android

If you need help, ask me!

Comment: What if I want to encode data to and display barcode as a bitmap on imageview?

Answer (score 3):

Display Barcode using Google barcode reader

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.ENCODE");   
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
intent.putExtra("ENCODE_TYPE", "TEXT_TYPE"); 
intent.putExtra("ENCODE_DATA",scan_code_main); // content part
intent.putExtra("ENCODE_FORMAT",scan_code_2); // format part

startActivity(intent);
```