# Barcode generation in java

Tags: java, swing, barcode

I am making an application to generate barcodes, but it does not give me the barcode: the application returns the text that I have provided. My code is:

```
Code39 code39=new Code39();
String outputStr=code39.encode("12345678", 1);
String humanTextStr=code39.getHumanText();
jLabel1.setText(outputStr);
jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("CCode39_S3",java.awt.Font.PLAIN,24));
```

Please can anyone tell me why this happens?

Comment: can you show us the Code39 class?

Comment: It's not clear what you're expecting to happen.

Comment: I want the Text I have provided is set JLabel1 as in barcode format But it gives me output is as:*12345678-*

Comment: @Duli-chan ..I hava Add ConnectCode Barcode Font Library.jar which contais Code39 class default..I have created Its Consrtuctor here only

Answer (score 6):

Your application is returning a text because you have told it to get the text not the bar-code.

Try the following code:

```
a=jTextField24.getText();      
Code39 barcode=new Code39();      
barcode.setData(a);      
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(barcode.drawBarcode());          
jLabel34.setIcon(icon);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using open source libraries for generating barcodes in java. For e.g., [iText](http://www.lowagie.com/iText/)  or http://barbecue.sourceforge.net/

Please refer to this link as well [BarCode Image Generator in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700597/barcode-image-generator-in-java/1700616#1700616)

Hope it helps.