# How to use Barcode in Java?

Tags: java, netbeans, barcode

I want to create barcodes and read it in java.
Id read about this but im not sure what to use.

For now, i'd read about Java Barcode API and BarcodeImageHandler.
Can anyone give me an advice to learn more about this?

I dont know if it have relevance but im using the NetBeans 7.1.2 IDE

Comment: possible duplicate of [BarCode Image Generator in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700597/barcode-image-generator-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) alongisde this [tutorial](http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-barcode-api) or you may be able to download a Barcode Font such as [Code38](http://www.barcodesinc.com/free-barcode-font/) or [IDAutomationHC39M](http://www.dafont.com/idautomationhc39m.font) and use this within you document.