# How to save the Scanned QR code images into image view in Android?

Tags: android, image, qr-code

I am use Zxing code for QR code reading. It's working fine.

My problem is how to display the scanned QR code into the image view.

please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Android Manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
```

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <activity
        android:name=".GenerateQRCodeActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Android Layout - main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">
 <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Input some text here ..."
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
 <EditText android:id="@+id/qrInput" android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:ems="10">

  <requestFocus />
 </EditText>
 <Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Generate QR Code" />
 <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Android Activity - GenerateQRCodeActivity.java

```
package com.as400samplecode;

import com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat;
import com.google.zxing.WriterException;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class GenerateQRCodeActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

 private String LOG_TAG = "GenerateQRCode";

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

  Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
  button1.setOnClickListener(this);

 }

 public void onClick(View v) {

  switch (v.getId()) {
  case R.id.button1:
   EditText qrInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.qrInput);
   String qrInputText = qrInput.getText().toString();
   Log.v(LOG_TAG, qrInputText);

   //Find screen size
   WindowManager manager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
   Display display = manager.getDefaultDisplay();
   Point point = new Point();
   display.getSize(point);
   int width = point.x;
   int height = point.y;
   int smallerDimension = width < height ? width : height;
   smallerDimension = smallerDimension * 3/4;

   //Encode with a QR Code image
   QRCodeEncoder qrCodeEncoder = new QRCodeEncoder(qrInputText,
             null,
             Contents.Type.TEXT, 
             BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE.toString(),
             smallerDimension);
   try {
    Bitmap bitmap = qrCodeEncoder.encodeAsBitmap();
    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    myImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

   } catch (WriterException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }


   break;

   // More buttons go here (if any) ...

  }
 }

}
```

Source for QRCodeEncoder.java

```
package com.as400samplecode;

import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.PhoneNumberUtils;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.EnumMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat;
import com.google.zxing.EncodeHintType;
import com.google.zxing.MultiFormatWriter;
import com.google.zxing.WriterException;
import com.google.zxing.common.BitMatrix;

public final class QRCodeEncoder {
    private static final int WHITE = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    private static final int BLACK = 0xFF000000;

    private int dimension = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    private String contents = null;
    private String displayContents = null;
    private String title = null;
    private BarcodeFormat format = null;
    private boolean encoded = false;

    public QRCodeEncoder(String data, Bundle bundle, String type, String format, int dimension) {
        this.dimension = dimension;
        encoded = encodeContents(data, bundle, type, format);
    }

    public String getContents() {
        return contents;
    }

    public String getDisplayContents() {
        return displayContents;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    private boolean encodeContents(String data, Bundle bundle, String type, String formatString) {
        // Default to QR_CODE if no format given.
        format = null;
        if (formatString != null) {
            try {
                format = BarcodeFormat.valueOf(formatString);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
                // Ignore it then
            }
        }
        if (format == null || format == BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE) {
            this.format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;
            encodeQRCodeContents(data, bundle, type);
        } else if (data != null && data.length() > 0) {
            contents = data;
            displayContents = data;
            title = "Text";
        }
        return contents != null && contents.length() > 0;
    }

    private void encodeQRCodeContents(String data, Bundle bundle, String type) {
        if (type.equals(Contents.Type.TEXT)) {
            if (data != null && data.length() > 0) {
                contents = data;
                displayContents = data;
                title = "Text";
            }
        } else if (type.equals(Contents.Type.EMAIL)) {
            data = trim(data);
            if (data != null) {
                contents = "mailto:" + data;
                displayContents = data;
                title = "E-Mail";
            }
        } else if (type.equals(Contents.Type.PHONE)) {
            data = trim(data);
            if (data != null) {
                contents = "tel:" + data;
                displayContents = PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(data);
                title = "Phone";
            }
        } else if (type.equals(Contents.Type.SMS)) {
            data = trim(data);
            if (data != null) {
                contents = "sms:" + data;
                displayContents = PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(data);
                title = "SMS";
            }
        } else if (type.equals(Contents.Type.CONTACT)) {
            if (bundle != null) {
                StringBuilder newContents = new StringBuilder(100);
                StringBuilder newDisplayContents = new StringBuilder(100);

                newContents.append("MECARD:");

                String name = trim(bundle.getString(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME));
                if (name != null) {
                    newContents.append("N:").append(escapeMECARD(name)).append(';');
                    newDisplayContents.append(name);
                }

                String address = trim(bundle.getString(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.POSTAL));
                if (address != null) {
                    newContents.append("ADR:").append(escapeMECARD(address)).append(';');
                    newDisplayContents.append('\n').append(address);
                }

                Collection<String> uniquePhones = new HashSet<String>(Contents.PHONE_KEYS.length);
                for (int x = 0; x < Contents.PHONE_KEYS.length; x++) {
                    String phone = trim(bundle.getString(Contents.PHONE_KEYS[x]));
                    if (phone != null) {
                        uniquePhones.add(phone);
                    }
                }
                for (String phone : uniquePhones) {
                    newContents.append("TEL:").append(escapeMECARD(phone)).append(';');
                    newDisplayContents.append('\n').append(PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(phone));
                }

                Collection<String> uniqueEmails = new HashSet<String>(Contents.EMAIL_KEYS.length);
                for (int x = 0; x < Contents.EMAIL_KEYS.length; x++) {
                    String email = trim(bundle.getString(Contents.EMAIL_KEYS[x]));
                    if (email != null) {
                        uniqueEmails.add(email);
                    }
                }
                for (String email : uniqueEmails) {
                    newContents.append("EMAIL:").append(escapeMECARD(email)).append(';');
                    newDisplayContents.append('\n').append(email);
                }

                String url = trim(bundle.getString(Contents.URL_KEY));
                if (url != null) {
                    // escapeMECARD(url) -> wrong escape e.g. http\://zxing.google.com
                    newContents.append("URL:").append(url).append(';');
                    newDisplayContents.append('\n').append(url);
                }

                String note = trim(bundle.getString(Contents.NOTE_KEY));
                if (note != null) {
                    newContents.append("NOTE:").append(escapeMECARD(note)).append(';');
                    newDisplayContents.append('\n').append(note);
                }

                // Make sure we've encoded at least one field.
                if (newDisplayContents.length() > 0) {
                    newContents.append(';');
                    contents = newContents.toString();
                    displayContents = newDisplayContents.toString();
                    title = "Contact";
                } else {
                    contents = null;
                    displayContents = null;
                }

            }
        } else if (type.equals(Contents.Type.LOCATION)) {
            if (bundle != null) {
                // These must use Bundle.getFloat(), not getDouble(), it's part of the API.
                float latitude = bundle.getFloat("LAT", Float.MAX_VALUE);
                float longitude = bundle.getFloat("LONG", Float.MAX_VALUE);
                if (latitude != Float.MAX_VALUE && longitude != Float.MAX_VALUE) {
                    contents = "geo:" + latitude + ',' + longitude;
                    displayContents = latitude + "," + longitude;
                    title = "Location";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public Bitmap encodeAsBitmap() throws WriterException {
        if (!encoded) return null;

        Map<EncodeHintType, Object> hints = null;
        String encoding = guessAppropriateEncoding(contents);
        if (encoding != null) {
            hints = new EnumMap<EncodeHintType, Object>(EncodeHintType.class);
            hints.put(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, encoding);
        }
        MultiFormatWriter writer = new MultiFormatWriter();
        BitMatrix result = writer.encode(contents, format, dimension, dimension, hints);
        int width = result.getWidth();
        int height = result.getHeight();
        int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
        // All are 0, or black, by default
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            int offset = y * width;
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                pixels[offset + x] = result.get(x, y) ? BLACK : WHITE;
            }
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
        return bitmap;
    }

    private static String guessAppropriateEncoding(CharSequence contents) {
        // Very crude at the moment
        for (int i = 0; i < contents.length(); i++) {
            if (contents.charAt(i) > 0xFF) { return "UTF-8"; }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static String trim(String s) {
        if (s == null) { return null; }
        String result = s.trim();
        return result.length() == 0 ? null : result;
    }

    private static String escapeMECARD(String input) {
        if (input == null || (input.indexOf(':') < 0 && input.indexOf(';') < 0)) { return input; }
        int length = input.length();
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(length);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            char c = input.charAt(i);
            if (c == ':' || c == ';') {
                result.append('\\');
            }
            result.append(c);
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

Source for Contents.java

```
package com.as400samplecode;

import android.provider.ContactsContract;

public final class Contents {
    private Contents() {
    }

    public static final class Type {

     // Plain text. Use Intent.putExtra(DATA, string). This can be used for URLs too, but string
     // must include "http://" or "https://".
        public static final String TEXT = "TEXT_TYPE";

        // An email type. Use Intent.putExtra(DATA, string) where string is the email address.
        public static final String EMAIL = "EMAIL_TYPE";

        // Use Intent.putExtra(DATA, string) where string is the phone number to call.
        public static final String PHONE = "PHONE_TYPE";

        // An SMS type. Use Intent.putExtra(DATA, string) where string is the number to SMS.
        public static final String SMS = "SMS_TYPE";


  //  A contact. Send a request to encode it as follows:
  //  <p/>
  //  import android.provider.Contacts;
  //  <p/>
  //  Intent intent = new Intent(Intents.Encode.ACTION); intent.putExtra(Intents.Encode.TYPE,
  //  CONTACT); Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); bundle.putString(Contacts.Intents.Insert.NAME,
  //  "Jenny"); bundle.putString(Contacts.Intents.Insert.PHONE, "8675309");
  //  bundle.putString(Contacts.Intents.Insert.EMAIL, "jenny@the80s.com");
  //  bundle.putString(Contacts.Intents.Insert.POSTAL, "123 Fake St. San Francisco, CA 94102");
  //  intent.putExtra(Intents.Encode.DATA, bundle);

        public static final String CONTACT = "CONTACT_TYPE";




        public static final String LOCATION = "LOCATION_TYPE";

        private Type() {
        }
    }

    public static final String URL_KEY = "URL_KEY";

    public static final String NOTE_KEY = "NOTE_KEY";

    // When using Type.CONTACT, these arrays provide the keys for adding or retrieving multiple
    // phone numbers and addresses.
    public static final String[] PHONE_KEYS = {
            ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.SECONDARY_PHONE,
            ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.TERTIARY_PHONE
    };

    public static final String[] PHONE_TYPE_KEYS = {
            ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE_TYPE,
            ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.SECONDARY_PHONE_TYPE,
            ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.TERTIARY_PHONE_TYPE
    };

    public static final String[] EMAIL_KEYS = {
            ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.EMAIL, ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.SECONDARY_EMAIL,
            ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.TERTIARY_EMAIL
    };

    public static final String[] EMAIL_TYPE_KEYS = {
            ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.EMAIL_TYPE,
            ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.SECONDARY_EMAIL_TYPE,
            ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.TERTIARY_EMAIL_TYPE
    };
}
```

Comment: Still, I have the problem that i want to display the QR code image while scanning (after scanning process is complete that time scanned QR image will be displayed in the imageview

Comment: i am also having the same problem.. while scanning means.... the qr code image will capture and immediately display the image in image view plz help.. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer you are looking for may be.

Try this tutorial. you will get the QR-CODE/BAR-CODE in the imageview residing in your app. http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/09/android-generate-qr-code-using-zxing.html

after getting your Bar-Code in the imageview, you can convert this as a bitmap as

```
ImageView v1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.mImage);
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bm = v1.getDrawingCache();
```

now you have your bitmap, you can play with it now.

Hope this helps you.

also see my question I have asked the same [How to store the Generated QR-Code as an image in SDCard (ZXing library)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16292893/how-to-store-the-generated-qr-code-as-an-image-in-sdcard-zxing-library)

Answer (score 0):

After scanned you have some result, from camera. This code is code for display `ImageView`

```
  bitmap = encodeAsBitmap(qrInput.getText().toString(), BarcodeFormat.CODE_128, 600, 300);
                    final ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                    myImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Replace `qrInput` with your result, and `BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE.TEXT` to your format of QR code

and add this for encode image.

```
Bitmap encodeAsBitmap(String contents, BarcodeFormat format, int img_width, int img_height) throws WriterException {
    String contentsToEncode = contents;
    if (contentsToEncode == null) {
        return null;
    }
    Map<EncodeHintType, Object> hints = null;
    String encoding = guessAppropriateEncoding(contentsToEncode);
    if (encoding != null) {
        hints = new EnumMap<EncodeHintType, Object>(EncodeHintType.class);
        hints.put(EncodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, encoding);

    }
    MultiFormatWriter writer = new MultiFormatWriter();
    BitMatrix result;
    try {
        result = writer.encode(contentsToEncode, format, img_width, img_height, hints);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
        // Unsupported format
        Log.d("XXX4", "Unsupported format -" + iae);
        Toast.makeText(this, iae.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry - Try Changing Content", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return null;
    }

    int width = result.getWidth();
    int height = result.getHeight();
    int[] pixels = new int[width * height];


    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        int offset = y * width;
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            pixels[offset + x] = result.get(x, y) ? BLACK : WHITE;
        }
    }

    int img_widths = 400;
    int img_heights = 400;

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);

    if (format == BarcodeFormat.DATA_MATRIX) {
        bitmap = drawScaledBitmap(bitmap, img_widths, img_heights);
    }
    return bitmap;

}

public Bitmap drawScaledBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int img_widths, int img_heights) {
    final int bmWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
    final int bmHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
    final int wScalingFactor = img_widths / bmWidth;
    final int hScalingFactor = img_heights / bmHeight;
    final int scalingFactor = Math.min(wScalingFactor, hScalingFactor);
    return scalingFactor > 1 ? Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bmWidth * scalingFactor, bmHeight * scalingFactor, false) : bitmap;
}

private static String guessAppropriateEncoding(CharSequence contents) {
    // Very crude at the moment
    for (int i = 0; i < contents.length(); i++) {
        if (contents.charAt(i) > 0xFF) {
            return "UTF-8";
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```