# How to convert number into barcode in android?

Tags: android, numbers, zxing

I want to convert a number to a bar-code. How would I got about this? I don't have a clue about where to start so please explain.
I have my barcode font but I'm not entirely sure that this is needed. But I have one anyway.

I will have a text input which I will enter a number which then displays a bar-code on the next page.

This is for android and I don't have any code because I don't know where to start.

Anyone have snippet that I could try?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/zxing/

Comment: You have tagged the question zxing. So you know where to look..

Comment: check out [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1700616/2345913)

Comment: i tried to Google ZXing but i dont know how to actually use it?

Comment: @xiHarpzZ please try it yourself and ask specific questions when a problem arises

Comment: Chck this link out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700597/barcode-image-generator-in-java/1700616#1700616

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try out iText Library for generating barcodes as mentioned in this link below:

[BarCode Image Generator in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700597/barcode-image-generator-in-java/1700616#1700616)

Comment: Thanks i will defo investigate this